# Increase the font size in text editor of ubuntu

Tags: text-editor, text

I am new to ubuntu10.10, the text editor font size are very small.I searched in the menu bar, no option in the text editor to increase the font size .
Or if not any shortcode to increase the zooming of screen like (ctrl++ in browser) .

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: First, Update your OS not because this will fix your issue, but because 10.10 is not supported anymore meaning you don't get any *updates*. If I'm not mistaken the Text Editor which is gEdit, uses monospaced fonts, this you can change from Appearance>Customize>Fonts>Monospace font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using "gedit" go to menus

Edit => Preferences

Select Fonts & Colors and increase the font size.
[image]

Comment: thanks finally i find out the solution by your suggestion Much appreciated your help thanks....

Comment: Please consider to upgrade your Ubuntu to 12.04 LTS or 12.10 because the Ubuntu 10.10 expired!

Answer (score 1):

I am not using `gedit`. Rather, I will suggest a way for increasing the text size in `Notepad`, as asked in the original question. The trouble with `Notepad` is that unlike `gedit` it does not have an `Edit` menu. So to access  preferences (in Ubuntu 18.04) use the dropdown present on the top left corner of the screen.

[image: Dropdown for Text Editor]

From the dropdown, click on `Preferences`. Then under `Font & Colors`, you can change the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the icon with three horizontal lines at the top right corner of Text Editor as shown, then go to Preferences > Fonts & Colors and pick a font size as suited :)

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]